# Захват камеры в Emgu проект на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv, emgu

Пробую Emgu. А именно захват видео с веб камеры. Приложение на Windows Forms нормально работает. Решил перейти на WPF и столкнулся с тем, что там нет контрола ImageBox. Я сделал через Windowsformshost. Все работает. Но я бы хотел использовать родной контрол Image. И тут у меня не получается, картинки нет.
Разметка:

```
<Image Name="imageBox" Height="500" Width="500"/>
<Button x:Name="captureButton" Content="Start" Click="captureButton_Click" 
          Margin="33,36,25,473" FontFamily="Arial" Grid.Column="1" 
          Width="60" Height="60"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private VideoCapture _capture = null;
    private bool _captureInProgress;
    private Mat _frame;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Инит EMGUU 

        CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
        try
        {
            _capture = new VideoCapture();
            // Подписываемся на событие
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }


        _frame = new Mat();

    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (_capture != null && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            _capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);

            var temp = _frame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Bitmap;

            using (Image<Bgr, byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
            {
                //Вот тут что-то не то =((((
                imageBox.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(frame);

                //  imageBox.Source = BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(temp as Image);
            }
        }
    }

    private void captureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_capture != null)
        {
            if (_captureInProgress)
            {  //stop the capture
                captureButton.Content = "Start Capture";
                _capture.Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                //start the capture
                captureButton.Content = "Stop";

                _capture.Start();
            }

            _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
        }
    }

    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (_capture != null)
            _capture.Dispose();
    }


}
```

Класс конвертер

```
 public static class BitmapSourceConvert
{
    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap();

            BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                ptr,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            DeleteObject(ptr);
            return bs;
        }
    }
}
```

В общем приложение компилируется, запускается, зажигается индикатор на веб камере, а изображения нет.

**ПС:** Если использовать

```
<WindowsFormsHost Width="550px" Height="550px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <emui:ImageBox x:Name="imageBox"></emui:ImageBox>
                    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

И в MainWindow.xaml.cs писать в контрол, подтянутый из WinForms:

```
 imageBox.Image = _frame;
```

Все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем у меня получилось сделать захват видео в штатный контрол Image
Привожу код:
Если нужно - github: [Пример](https://github.com/Ledrunning/ComputerVision/tree/Dev/FaceDetector)
Собственно XAML(Отсутствует кнопка...):

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfFaceDetectionTest.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="600" 
     Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
     <Grid>
         <Image Name="imageBox" Stretch="Fill" />
     </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Основной код:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
private VideoCapture _capture = null;
private bool _captureInProgress;
private Mat _frame;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Инит EMGUU 

    CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
    try
    {
        _capture = new VideoCapture();
        // Подписываемся на событие
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
    }


    _frame = new Mat();

}
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (capture != null && capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => imageBox.Source = 
            BitmapSourceConvert.ToBitmapSource(_frame as IImage)));
        }
    }

private void captureButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_capture != null)
    {
        if (_captureInProgress)
        {  //stop the capture
            captureButton.Content = "Start Capture";
            _capture.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            //start the capture
            captureButton.Content = "Stop";

            _capture.Start();
        }

        _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
    }
}

private void ReleaseData()
{
    if (_capture != null)
        _capture.Dispose();
}
}
```

Класс конвертер:

```
public static class BitmapSourceConvert
{
[DllImport("gdi32")]
private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap();

        BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            ptr,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        DeleteObject(ptr);
        return bs;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал рабочий тестовый проект, обработчик у меня получился следующего вида:

```
  private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj))
        {
            if (_capture != null && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    using (Image<Bgr, byte> emguFrame = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>())
                    {
                        imageBox.Source = Convert(emguFrame.Bitmap);
                    }
                }));
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
        }

    }
```

Код конвертации Bitmap в BitmapSource:

```
 public BitmapSource Convert(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        PixelFormatConverter convert = new PixelFormatConverter();

        var bitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(
            bitmapData.Width, bitmapData.Height, 96, 96, ConvertPixelFormat(bitmap.PixelFormat), null,
            bitmapData.Scan0, bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height, bitmapData.Stride);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        return bitmapSource;
    }

    private static System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat ConvertPixelFormat(System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat sourceFormat)
    {
        switch (sourceFormat)
        {
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
                return PixelFormats.Bgr24;

            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
                return PixelFormats.Bgra32;

            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
                return PixelFormats.Bgr32;
            case System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
                return PixelFormats.Gray16;

            default:
                return PixelFormats.Bgr24;
        }

    }
```

P.S. Возможно Вам пригодится. Я в своем проекте делал захват видео с помощью Accord Framework .NET [ссылка](http://accord-framework.net/), отображение делал на WPF при помощи `Image` контрола и класса `WritableBitmap`. Небольшая модификация кода Accord Framework .NET, позволила получить не `Bitmap`, а указатель на массив байт, который с дополнительными параметрами передавал методу `WritePixels` объекта класса `WriteablreBitmap`, это работало быстрее и избавляло от необходимости конвертации `Bitmap`.

Comment: Спасибо! Я попробую ваше решение. Сейчас я победил свой проект. И у меня получилось захват видео реализовать через штатный контрол Image.

Comment: @JDo, приведите пожалуйста пример реализации.